# Best WCF 3.5 for Silverlight 3 learning sources?

Tags: wcf, silverlight-3.0

I was learning WCF 3.5 and I already know some Silverlight (Basically what I've been learning while deloping in WPF which is transferable to Silverlight), and I just noticed that creating WCF services for Silverlight is a little different than 'regular' WCF services. I've been looking for books that concentrate in this topic, but all I've found is Web Services for Silverlight, which is not what I need.

So, I'm trying to find other learning sources on this topic. So if you guys have any experience with this, or any blog posts, etc., it would help me a lot if you shared it with the programmer community here.

Thanks!

Additions:

[Silverlight 3 and .net RIA Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/07/10/amazing-business-apps-example-updated-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update.aspx) - by Goblin

Answer (score 0):

I've learned all I know about RIA services (wrapped async WCF services) from Brad Adams. He has a 20'ish part blog-series about using the RIA-services in a Silverlight app - starts [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/07/10/amazing-business-apps-example-updated-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update.aspx).